# Existing items in listview disappears while refreshing, when no internet connection android

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask, refresh

I am having a listview which contains custom layout . I am retriving data from server and displaying it in the listview view .

I am using [Pull to refresh listview](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) library

With internet connection available ---> when I pull to refresh , the data successfully gets updated

With NO internet connection available ---> when I pull to refresh , the existing data disappears leaving the listview empty, which is not expected

I want the existing data to be still visible, when no internet connection available.

HomeFragent.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_layout, container,false);
        View footer_image=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_image_footer, null,false);
        //footer_image.setClickable(false);


            /* get theme webservice*/

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy1 = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy1); 


        userFunction=new UserFunctions();

            //Breaking News Section
            slide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slidedown);
            fadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fadeout);
            pan_breaking_new = (LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pan_breaking_new);
            //pan_breaking_new.setOnClickListener(this);    
            pan_breaking_new.setVisibility(8);

            btn_close= (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_close);
            btn_close.setOnClickListener(this);
            img_share= (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_share);
            img_share.setOnClickListener(this);
            //END Breaking News Section

            //Ticker
            marque = (ScrollingTextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtTicker);
            marque.setVisibility(8);
            //END ticker


            main_error = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_error);
            main_error.setText("Loading...");
            img_error = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.img_error);
            img_error.setOnClickListener(this);


            progressBar1 = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            progressBar1.setVisibility(8);



            //karthik
            refreshable_listView = (PullToRefreshListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
            listView=refreshable_listView.getRefreshableView();
            listView.addFooterView(footer_image, null, false);

            refreshable_listView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ListView>() {

                @Override
                public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                     listView=refreshable_listView.getRefreshableView();                        

                    try {
                        getTheme();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    new GetList().execute(index_th);

                }


            });     
            newsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(), newsList);                            
            refreshable_listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);




            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {     
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {

                news_flag= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.flag);
                news_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fid);
                news_live = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.live);
                news_title_live = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);


                //news_flag.getText().toString();
                //Log.e("-->", news_flag.getText().toString());

                //checking for click banner or neews
                if(news_flag.getText().toString().equals("normal")){

                    // Starting a new async task
                    new ViewSingleNews().execute();

                }else{

                    /*Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(All_link.IMAGE_URI_BANNER+news_flag.getText().toString()),"image/*");

                    startActivity(intent);*/
                }



            }

        });
        listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                int count = Integer.parseInt(index_temp)+6;
                System.out.println("Checking "+ listView.getLastVisiblePosition());
                System.out.println("----->Checking loadmore:"+ load_more);
                System.out.println("----->Checking actual:"+ count);

                   if (listView.getLastVisiblePosition()+1  == count) {

                       if(load_more==1){


                            index_temp = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(icount) + Integer.parseInt(index_temp));

                            new GetList_ontouch().execute(index_temp);
                        }
                    }
            }
        });

        //listView.addHeaderView(pan_breaking_new);
        mSeparatorsSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        mSeparatorsSet_alternate_layout = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        mSeparatorsSet_live_layout = new TreeSet<Integer>();

        new GetList_img_error().execute(index_th); // same as GetList(), but displays dialog 

        return rootView;
```

}

```
private class GetList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        String jsonStr;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> Local_newsList;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            if (NetworkCheck.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity()) == true) {

                //Log.d("index count for array", params[0]);
                if(Integer.parseInt(params[0])==0){
                    //Log.d("index count for array","Rweached");
                    //newsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                }


                // Creating service handler class instance
                ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

                // Making a request to url and getting response
                jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(All_link.HOME_DATA_URL + "/"+params[0]+"/"+ icount,
                        ServiceHandler.GET);

                Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        news = jsonObj.getJSONArray(All_link.TAG_NEWS);


                        err = jsonObj.getString(All_link.TAG_ERROR);
                        String more = jsonObj.getString(All_link.TAG_MORE);

                        Log.e("------>Error",String.valueOf(err));
                        Log.e("------>More",String.valueOf(more));
                        if(more.equals("0")){

                            load_more = 0;

                        }else{

                            load_more = 1;
                        }

                        // looping through All Contacts
                        for (int i = 0; i < news.length(); i++) {

                            //karthik



                            JSONObject segments_list = news.getJSONObject(i);

                            for (int plates_count = 0; plates_count < segments_list
                                    .length(); plates_count++) {


                                String plates = "";
                                if (plates_count == 3) {
                                    plates = String.valueOf("banner_image");

                                    JSONObject segments_plates = segments_list
                                            .getJSONObject(plates);

                                    //String flag = "banner_image";
                                    String id = segments_plates
                                            .getString(All_link.TAG_BANNER_ID);
                                    String banner_no = segments_plates
                                            .getString(All_link.TAG_BANNER_NO);

                                    String banner_image;

                                    if(segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_BANNER_THUMB_URL)==""){

                                        banner_image = All_link.TAG_NO_IMAGE;
                                    }else{

                                        banner_image = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_BANNER_THUMB_URL);
                                    }

                                    String banner_status = segments_plates
                                            .getString(All_link.TAG_BANNER_STATUS);


                                    // tmp hashmap for single news
                                    HashMap<String, String> news_hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                    // adding each child node to HashMap key =>
                                    // value
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_BANNER_ID, id);
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_BANNER_NO,
                                            banner_no);
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_BANNER_THUMB_URL,
                                            banner_image);
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_BANNER_STATUS,
                                            banner_status);
                                    /*news_hashmap
                                            .put(All_link.TAG_BANNER_FLAG, flag);*/

                                    // adding contact to contact list



                                    newsList.add(news_hashmap);


                                    //karthik newsList

                                    //Local_newsList.add(news_hashmap);


                                    addSeparatorItem();
                                } else {
                                    plates = String.valueOf(plates_count + 1);

                                    JSONObject segments_plates = segments_list
                                            .getJSONObject(plates);

                                    if(segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_NEWS_TYPE).equals("2")){

                                        //type_of_news = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_NEWS_TYPE);
                                        addSeparatorItem_for_live();
                                    }                                   

                                    String id = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_ID);
                                    String news_title = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_NEWS_TITLE);
                                    String news_desc = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_DESC);
                                    String segment = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_SEGMENT);
                                    String plate = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_PLATE);

                                    String img ="";
                                    if(segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_THUMB_URL).equals("")){

                                        img = All_link.TAG_NO_IMAGE;

                                    }else{

                                        img = segments_plates.getString(All_link.TAG_THUMB_URL);
                                    }


                                    HashMap<String, String> news_hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                    // adding each child node to HashMap key =>
                                    // value
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_ID, id);
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_NEWS_TITLE, news_title);
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_DESC, news_desc);
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_SEGMENT, segment);
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_PLATE, plate);
                                    news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_THUMB_URL, img);
                                    //news_hashmap.put(All_link.TAG_BANNER_FLAG, flag);
                                    // adding contact to contact list

                                    newsList.add(news_hashmap);



                                    //karthik newsList

                                    //Local_newsList.add(news_hashmap);

                                    int val = 0;
                                    int val2 = 1;
                                    val = (Integer.parseInt(segment)%2)==0 ? val:val2;

                                    if((Integer.parseInt(segment)%2)!=0){
                                        Log.e("--->CHECKING ODD EVEN", String.valueOf(val));
                                        addSeparatorItem();
                                        addSeparatorItem_for_alternate();   
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Local_newsList=null;
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Network Error", "Internet Connection Error");
                error_flag = 1;
                // error = "Internet Connection Error";

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {     

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            refreshable_listView.invalidate();
            refreshable_listView.requestLayout();
            refreshable_listView.onRefreshComplete();


            super.onPostExecute(result);


            if(error_flag==1){

                listView.setVisibility(8);
                main_error.setText("Internet Connection Error! Please check your network settings and try again");
                main_error.setVisibility(0);
                img_error.setVisibility(0);

            }else{

                listView.setVisibility(0);
                main_error.setText("");
                main_error.setVisibility(8);
                img_error.setVisibility(8);
                int currentPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(), newsList);
                //testing
                listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                refreshable_listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                 // Setting new scroll position
                listView.setSelection(currentPosition);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(All_link.MyPREFERENCES,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

            //For Breaking News Setting
            if (sharedPrefs.getInt("prefswtch4", 1) == 1) {

                if (All_link.GLOBAL_BREAKING_FLAG == 0) {

                    new getBreakingNews().execute();

                }

            } 

            //For Location Setting
            if (sharedPrefs.getInt("prefswtch1", 1) == 1) {



            } else {



            }

            //For Ticker Setting
            if (sharedPrefs.getInt("prefswtch2", 1) == 1) {

                new getTicker().execute();

            } else {

                marque.setVisibility(8);

            }




        }
        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            refreshable_listView.onRefreshComplete();
        }

    }
```

Comment: u probably need to store your data in storage for offline access. whenever u refresh, update the database and whenever internet connection is not available, load the data from the offline database.

Comment: Would this make my app heavy ? . Is there is any other alternative to do this by code ?

Comment: it wont make ur app heavy.... and for the alternative, u can use LruCache... but using sqlite will be easier i guess

Comment: Can u pls help me to get started how to go for saving which data in  database ...  A sample code ..

Comment: ohk... i dont know how much u know, so from where to begin? Are u good at sqlite database?

Comment: yeah ... I have knowledge of sqlite , but don't know how to go with  this situation ...

Comment: ohk then... create a new listview with cursor adapter... for this listview use the araylist in which u recieve the online data.. then populate the listview and store data in the sqlite database. dont make it visible to users)... for better performance, do these things in asynctask class

Comment: ok...let me try this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem .

I just saved the String `jsonStr` in SharedPreference , and created separate

```
class GetList_refresh extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>
```

and called `new GetList_refresh().execute(index_th,jsonStr);` , when no network is avalabile.

Its working perfectly as expected ...